# Spring mongo adding criteria to and operator dynamicaly

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

I am trying to create dynamic query with user input with and operation 
My code is
I created List of criteria like:

```
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
```

and added criteria to this list.And its getting added successfully. now I want to make and operator between each criteria.

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.get(0), criterias.get(1));
```

It works fine But my input is not fixed so I want it should added dynamically,
I tried like

```
for(int i=0;i<criterias.size();i++)
  Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.get(i));
```

where I am missing?

Comment: Not too sure what you are going for here. Are you perhaps trying to add a list of conditions to the **`$and`** operator? It might help if you showed the JSON equivalent (or basic shell version) of the query you are trying to construct dynamically.

Comment: @ Neil Lunn I am trying to create $and but I can not use andoperator on same field so I need to add like    Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.get(0), criterias.get(1));

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To unite all criterias from a list of criterias by "$and" operator :

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.size()]));
```

here is [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.4.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#andOperator%28org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria...%29)